# Scala: in where clause how to get column string value and split, and intersect against another array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe where one column is ; separated strings, e.g. "str1;str2;str3;str4", I also have another static list "strx;stry;strz", the goal is to split the column string value and check if the split array has any intersection with the static list, and keep that row

I tried

```
df.where($"column".split(";").intersect(staticList).nonEmpty)

or df.where(split($"column", ";").intersect(staticList).nonEmpty)

or replace $"" with col()

or use $"".getString before calling split
```

I always get error `split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName`, similar to `getString`. It appears the split is applied to a Column type instead of String type.

So my question is, during where or filter, how can I access the string value for a column and split it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up Spark's `split` method for Columns with Scala's `split` for Strings.  Please see example below for how the two different `split` methods are used.  Method [`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array_intersect(col1:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,col2:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is for intersecting the split Array column with the split element-filter string.

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "a;b;c;d"),
  (2, "u;v;w")
).toDF("id", "csv_str")

val filterCsvStr = "a;c;x;y"

val df2 = df.withColumn("wanted_strs", array_intersect(
    split($"csv_str", ";"),
    lit(filterCsvStr.split(";"))
  )
)

df2.show
// +---+-------+-----------+
// | id|csv_str|wanted_strs|
// +---+-------+-----------+
// |  1|a;b;c;d|     [a, c]|
// |  2|  u;v;w|         []|
// +---+-------+-----------+

df2.where(size($"wanted_strs") > 0).show
// +---+-------+-----------+
// | id|csv_str|wanted_strs|
// +---+-------+-----------+
// |  1|a;b;c;d|     [a, c]|
// +---+-------+-----------+
```

A couple of notes:

1. Method `array_intersect` removes duplicate elements in the Array column.
2. [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is for converting the Scala list to a `Column` as `array_intersect` expects Column-typed arguments.

---

If the element filters are available as values of a `Column`, arguments for the `array_intersect` will be simpler:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "a;b;c;d", "b;c;e"),
  (2, "u;v;w", "t;v")
).toDF("id", "csv_str", "filter_csv_str")

val df2 = df.withColumn("wanted_strs", array_intersect(
    split($"csv_str", ";"),
    split($"filter_csv_str", ";")
  )
)

df2.show
// +---+-------+--------------+-----------+
// | id|csv_str|filter_csv_str|wanted_strs|
// +---+-------+--------------+-----------+
// |  1|a;b;c;d|         b;c;e|     [b, c]|
// |  2|  u;v;w|           t;v|        [v]|
// +---+-------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!! one more question, in order for later easy process, getting true/false from above is not enough, e.g. column has str1;str2;str3;str4, target static list is str2;str4. I want to remove str1 and str3 from the column and keep only 2/4, how can I do that? even further, given the static list is limited, I can add extra columns for each str2 and str4, in this case, for str1;str2;str3;str4, I'll mark T for both new columns for str2 and str4. Is it doable?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your revised requirement.  Please see my expanded answer.